# Which prophet talked with God face to face

Tags: deuteronomy, moses, joshua

Jewish understanding of Deut. 18:18 is that the prophet like Moses is Joshua. Deut. 34:10 says to be like Moses means that the prophet would talk with God face to face. Did Joshua talk with God like that? Joshua 1:1-5 says God spoke to Joshua but doesn't say face to face.
Also we know that it was Angel of the Lord who talked to Moses from bush and it is said at the same time that it was God:

> Ex.3:2 And the angel of the LORD appeared unto him in a flame of fire
> out of the midst of a bush: and he looked, and, behold, the bush
> burned with fire, and the bush was not consumed. Ex.3:3 And Moses
> said, I will now turn aside, and see this great sight, why the bush is
> not burnt. Ex.3:4 And when the LORD saw that he turned aside to see,
> God called unto him out of the midst of the bush, and said, Moses,
> Moses. And he said, Here am I.

Another place when God talks to Moses from the cloud that settled on Sinai

> Ex.19:18 Now Mount Sinai was completely in smoke, because the LORD
> descended upon it in fire. Its smoke ascended like the smoke of a
> furnace, and the whole mountain quaked greatly. Ex.19:19 And when the
> blast of the trumpet sounded long and became louder and louder, Moses
> spoke, and God answered him by voice. Ex.19:20 Then the LORD came down
> upon Mount Sinai, on the top of the mountain. And the LORD called
> Moses to the top of the mountain, and Moses went up. Ex.19:21 And the
> LORD said to Moses, «Go down and warn the people, lest they break
> through to gaze at the LORD, and many of them perish.

And the Angel and God were going with Israel in the cloud:

> Ex.13:21 And the LORD went before them by day in a pillar of a cloud,
> to lead them the way; and by night in a pillar of fire, to give them
> light; to go by day and night:
>
> Ex.14:19 And the angel of God, which went before the camp of Israel,
> removed and went behind them; and the pillar of the cloud went from
> before their face, and stood behind them
> So it must the Angel who was talking to Moses on Sinai mount also

So it might be that it was actually the Angel who settled on Sinai and talked to Moses as it was with burning bush

Maybe it is that Angel who appears to Joshua here:

> Josh.5:13 And it came to pass, when Joshua was by Jericho, that he
> lifted up his eyes and looked, and, behold, there stood a man over
> against him with his sword drawn in his hand: and Joshua went unto
> him, and said unto him, Art thou for us, or for our adversaries?
> Josh.5:14 And he said, Nay; but as captain of the host of the LORD am
> I now come. And Joshua fell on his face to the earth, and did worship,
> and said unto him, What saith my lord unto his servant? Josh.5:15 And
> the captain of the LORD'S host said unto Joshua, Loose thy shoe from
> off thy foot; for the place whereon thou standest is holy. And Joshua
> did so. Josh.6:1 Now Jericho was straitly shut up because of the
> children of Israel: none went out, and none came in. Josh.6:2 And the
> LORD said unto Joshua, See, I have given into thine hand Jericho, and
> the king thereof, and the mighty men of valour.

Here also the angel talks and then it is said "Lord said unto Joshua"

Answer (score 1):

This is quite uncomplicated because we are explicitly told by the inspired writers of the NT who fulfilled this prophecy in Deut 18:18 -

> Acts 3:21-23 - Heaven must take Him in until the time comes for the
> restoration of all things, which God announced long ago through His
> holy prophets. For Moses said, ‘The Lord your God will raise up for
> you a prophet like me from among your brothers. You must listen to Him
> in everything He tells you.  Everyone who does not listen to Him will
> be completely cut off from among his people.’

It was Jesus Christ Himself!

Now, let us be very clear that numerous other people are recorded as seeing the LORD face to face; here is a sample:

- Isa 64:4 - From ancient times no one has heard, no ear has perceived, no eye has seen any God besides You, who acts on behalf of those who wait for Him.
- Job 42:5 - My ears had heard of You [= the LORD, V1], but now my eyes have seen You.
- Gen 18:1, 10 - Then the LORD appeared to Abraham by the Oaks of Mamre in the heat of the day, while he was sitting at the entrance of his tent. ... Then the LORD said, “I will surely return to you at this time next year, and your wife Sarah will have a son!”
- Gen 32:30 - So Jacob called the place Peniel, saying, “It is because I saw God face to face, and yet my life was spared.”
- Ex 3:5, 6 - “Do not come any closer,” God said. “Take off your sandals, for the place where you are standing is holy ground.” Then He said, “I am the God of your father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob.”
- Josh 5:13 - 6:2 - And the LORD said to Joshua, “Behold, I have delivered Jericho into your hand, along with its king and its mighty men of valor.” (V2)
- Judges 6:14 - The LORD turned to him and said, “Go in the strength you have and save Israel from the hand of Midian. Am I not sending you?” [See also V16]
  Judges 16:22 - “We are going to die,” he said to his wife, “for we have seen God!”

However, the fact that these people saw God face to face does not necessarily make them the fulfilment of the prophecy - that question is answered by its direct fulfilment in the ministry and teaching of Jesus.